# p:selectBooleanCheckbox in a dialog can not be checked in IE11

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-7.0

p:selectBooleanCheckbox in a dialog can not be checked in IE11.
But it can be checked when drag-click.

```
<p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="_myDialog" header="dialog" closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false" closable="true" width="600">
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="a" itemLabel="Basic" />
 </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Since you tagged it PF-7 I assume it works in PF-6? And please, [mcve]  and it works in all other browsers too?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you for your replay. It has been worked out by updating the last version of jquery.ui.touch-punch.js. Idea comes from https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4297.

Answer (score 0):

Update the last version of jquery.ui.touch-punch.js, it works in IE11.
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js